# Purpose of guihandles in programmatic Matlab GUI design

Tags: matlab, user-interface, appdata, handles

I'm working on a fairly complex (for me) GUI in Matlab, made programmatically without GUIDE.

The different but similar ways to organize GUI objects confuse me. Please tell me where my understanding is incorrect, and if they're actually different at all:

What is the functional difference between the two following *handles* structures:

1) A *handles* populated by the... handles?... of GUI objects created explicitly with a *handles.* prefix. The *guidata* function is used in Callback functions to grab an up-to-date copy of *handles* and then save it.

```
handles.button = uicontrol(...);
guidata(handles.fig,handles);
```

appears in *handles* as *button*.

2) A *handles* populated by the *'Tag'* fields of GUI objects in a figure *fig*. This structure is created, after(?) drawing all of your GUI objects, using *guihandles*.

```
button = uicontrol(...'Parent',fig,'Tag','push'...);
handles = guihandles(fig);
```

appears in *handles* as *push*.

The *guidata* function doesn't seem to save to the handles struct made by *guihandles*. Is it necessary to instead use *handles = guihandles(fig)* at the end of every Callback?

Or am I thinking about the second type of structure wrong, and is bothering with the *handles.* prefix unnecessary altogether? Because creating a new GUI object and immediately entering just

```
guihandles
```

into the console shows the new GUI object listed with my old GUI objects. But I see this new object is stored openly in my Workspace, and is not under *handles* until I use

```
handles = guihandles;
```

again.

I apologize if it takes a re-read or two of all of the above to get what I'm asking.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between the two handles structures that you mention. Both structures should be the same.

It is necessary to use `handles=guihandles(fig);` instead of `guihandles` by itself because you need to tell Matlab where to store the results of the `guihandles` function. If you do not give it a variable to store the results to on the left hand side of the equals sign, it will store your resulting structure in the `ans` variable.

It's not necessary to create the handles structure at the end of each callback. You should be able to use `guihandles` to create your handles structure only as you need it.